# param is missing or the value is empty: record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am using Ruby on Rails to show an table, this is the code in view:

```
<h1> Show by category</h1>

<h2> table </h2>

<table border="1" style="width:70%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>SKU</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th><%= link_to "New",new_record_path %>
  </tr>

  <%= @records.each do |r| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= r.name %></td>
      <td><%= r.sku %></td>
      <td><%= r.category %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_record_path(r) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
      <%= will_paginate @records %>
</table>
```

and I got this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUN0v.png

Between the headline and the table, the records are all shown up, I don't know where it is coming from, can somebody help?

Comment: The title for this question is wrong, my browser remember my last draft..

Comment: Your title is not related to your problem at all! And to answer your problem just remove `=` here in this line `<%= @records.each do |r| %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here in this line

```
<%= @records.each do |r| %>
```

which should be

```
<% @records.each do |r| %>
```

***Imp note:***

```
<% %> #Executes the statement/expression.

<%= %> #Prints the output.
```